# how can I determine internet speed in my react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to determine internet speed in my react native app but no success
I've looked through some packages like `react-internet-meter`, `react-native-network-bandwith-speed`...but it only works on android

can anyone help me?

Comment: Download a file and measure much time it takes.  Repeat for upload.  The speed is the number of bytes transferred divided by the amount of time it took.

Comment: I've to do the same and I'll try this option, similar to @Wyck suggestion:
https://gist.github.com/mjm918/e1c00faca696a4ff88e998db6f4ef4e0